# WordPress: Changing comment_form(); $defaults in plug-in

Tags: php, wordpress, comments

I'm using the extend comment plugin to change the `comment_form();` drastically. Now I want to control the values of the `$default` options in the plugin. Tested the PHP below, but got the following error:

php:

```
add_filter( 'comment_form_defaults', $defaults );

function custom_defaults($defaults) {
    $comment_field_hide = '';

    $defaults[ 'label_submit' ] = 'fooBar';
    return $defaults;

}
```

EDIT: Changed according to the comment below, error is gone, but function doesn't take effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, the method is "[add_filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/)"... that's the error. Remove the "s"

it seems you do not use parameters the right way too... Second parameter should be the function's name, so change it to :

```
add_filter( 'comment_form_defaults', 'custom_defaults' );

function custom_defaults($defaults) {
    $comment_field_hide = '';

    $defaults[ 'label_submit' ] = 'fooBar';
    return $defaults;

}
```

Comment: Have a look to the add_filter method, it seems you do not use parameters the right way too... :) Second parameter should be the function's name.

Comment: Well. I really new that... was just a bit sloppy with this one o_O.

Comment: Yeah, you learn by trying. Wordpress is well made, so all plugins have to do the same kind of stuff in order to work, so you may check any plugin's code, and see how they handle their methods...